# Can't compile libpd with emmake (Emscripten SDK)

Tags: llvm-clang, emscripten, webassembly, stdatomic, libpd

I'm trying to compile [libpd](https://github.com/libpd/libpd) to javascript or webassembly using emscripten sdk. According to some docs, if there is a Makefile, it can be compiled by using `emmake make`, (emconfigure is not used because there is no ./configure file), but I get the following error:

```
/home/ian/Documents/emsdk/emscripten/1.37.37/emcc.py -DPD -DHAVE_UNISTD_H -DUSEAPI_DUMMY -I./pure-data/src -I./libpd_wrapper -I./libpd_wrapper/util -Wno-int-to-pointer-cast -Wno-pointer-to-int-cast -fPIC -I"/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include/linux" -DHAVE_LIBDL -ffast-math -funroll-loops -fomit-frame-pointer -O3 -DLIBPD_EXTRA      -c -o pure-data/src/d_array.o pure-data/src/d_array.c
pure-data/src/d_array.c:523:2: error: No byte order defined
#error No byte order defined
 ^
1 error generated.
ERROR:root:compiler frontend failed to generate LLVM bitcode, halting
<integrado>: fallo en las instrucciones para el objetivo 'pure-data/src/d_array.o'
make: *** [pure-data/src/d_array.o] Error 1
```

Any ideas? Do you think is possible to compile this library?

UPDATE: After tweaking every complaining file as suggested in @zakki 's answer
I get another error:

```
libpd_wrapper/util/ringbuffer.c:18:12: fatal error: 'stdatomic.h' file not found
  #include <stdatomic.h>
```

That file have this content:

```
#if __STDC_VERSION__ >= 201112L // use stdatomic if C11 is available
  #include <stdatomic.h> // HERE IS WHERE ERROR GOES
  #define SYNC_FETCH(ptr) atomic_fetch_or((_Atomic int *)ptr, 0)
  #define SYNC_COMPARE_AND_SWAP(ptr, oldval, newval) \
          atomic_compare_exchange_strong((_Atomic int *)ptr, &oldval, newval)
//Some other definitions that I didn't put here
```

I read some threads some time ago about this problem with C++11, how can i fix this?

UPDATE 2: After adding `&& !defined(__EMSCRIPTEN__)` now is able to compile, but I'm getting this warning that I don't understand:

> WARNING:root:Dynamic libraries (.so, .dylib, .dll) are currently not
>   supported by Emscripten. For build system emulation purposes,
>   Emscripten will now generate a static library file (.bc) with the
>   suffix '.so'. For best practices, please adapt your build system to
>   directly generate a static LLVM bitcode library by setting the output
>   suffix to '.bc.')

Comment: If you're compiling as C++11, that would be a problem.  [`<stdatomic.h>` is an (optional) C11 feature](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic).  C++11 uses `<atomic>`.  Your code is C, not C++, so make sure you compile it with a C compiler.  BTW, the library should (in theory at least) also check `!defined(__STDC_NO_ATOMICS__)`, because `__STDC_VERSION__ >= 201112L` doesn't guarantee support for atomics.

Comment: Perhaps `SOLIB_EXT` in `Makefile` should be `js`, And some extra codes to export functions is needed. https://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/porting/connecting_cpp_and_javascript/Interacting-with-code.html

Comment: https://mathr.co.uk/empd/ I've done work on it it recently, the dynamic linking is a pain (so far I am statically linking all externals and calling their `foo_setup()` functions).  Harder (but not insurmountable) is Emscripten's insistence on not calling function pointers at different types to the true type of the function.

Comment: Nice! I'll check your work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Emscripten has `endian.h`. So add `defined(__EMSCRIPTEN__)` to ifdef.

```
#if defined(__linux__) || defined(__CYGWIN__) || defined(__GNU__) || \
    defined(ANDROID) || defined(__EMSCRIPTEN__)
#include <endian.h>
#endif
```

Second, it seems like [Emscripten bug](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/issues/5224).

```
#if __STDC_VERSION__ >= 201112L && !defined(__EMSCRIPTEN__)
```

Comment: That helped me to resolve that problem, but now i got that another one. I updated post to describe it